# Selection sort - Swap with next smallest vs smallest overall

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

I have a question about selection sort. In the below example -

> 12 8 7 5 2

will the next step be

> 8 12 7 5 2

or

> 2 8 7 5 12

?

The reason being that from the pseudocode, it seems that we simply look for the **first** element having a value smaller than the existing first rather than the **smallest overall**. So by that logic, the element to be swapped with 12 should be 8 instead of 2, right?

This is the pseudocode I am working with -

```
static int[] selectionSort(int[] input) {
    if (input.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        int pos = -1;
        for (int i=0;i<input.length-1;i++) {
            pos = i;
            for (int j=i+1;j<input.length;j++) {
                if (input[j] < input[pos]) {
                    int temp = input[pos];
                    input[pos] = input[j];
                    input[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

Is there something wrong with my understanding? Which of the 2 steps would be the correct one? The code should ideally result in the first option, shouldn't it?

Thanks!

Comment: In a selection sort, one divides the array into two parts - the sorted and unsorted parts. One then repeatedly searches the unsorted part for the next item to go into the sorted part, and swaps that item with the first item in the unsorted part - putting that item at the end of the newly expanded sorted part. So you **always** search the unsorted part to _select_ the smallest (or largest) item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In selection sort, you need find out the minimum element in the remaining array and swap those two.

So in your example, next step should be `2 8 7 5 12`. The only change needed in your code is to defer the swapping till the end, so only the smallest element will be swapped.

```
static int[] selectionSort(int[] input) {
    if (input.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        int pos = -1;
        for (int i=0;i<input.length-1;i++) {
            pos = i;
            for (int j=i+1;j<input.length;j++) {
                if (input[j] < input[pos]) {
                    pos = j;
                }
            }
            int temp = input[pos];
            input[pos] = input[i];
            input[i] = temp;
        }       
    }
    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You start with:

```
12 8 7 5 2
```

You start with no elements in the sorted portion, and you iterate through until you find the smallest in the unsorted portion. Then swap that with the first element in the unsorted portion.

```
sorted  |  unsorted
2          8 7 5 12
```

Iterate until you find the smallest, and swap with the first in the unsorted portion:

```
sorted  |  unsorted
2 5         7 8 12
```

Repeat a few times (no swaps required because elements are already in order):

```
sorted  |  unsorted
2 5 7       8 12

sorted  |  unsorted
2 5 7 8     12

sorted  
2 5 7 8 12
```

---

So your 2nd example is the correct first move.

Answer (score 1):

It will be `2, 8, 7, 5, 12`. Selection sort always brings the smallest element out to the left. Think of selection sort as the opposite of bubble sort. Where bubble sort **bubbles** the largest element to the right, selection sort does the opposite. I hope that helps.